# Validating with knockout-validation

Tags: knockout-validation

Working with knockout.js (and knockout-validation) I have this:

```
self.nickname = ko.observable("").extend({
    required: true,
    minLength: 3
});
```

and

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: nickname" class="short" maxlength="30" />
<div class="formRow rowErrorMsg" data-bind="visible: nickname.isValid() == false"><span class="staticImages staticImagesError"></span> <?php text("Enter a valid username") ?></div>
```

but the problem is that when "nickname" its not valid then apper a text next to the input control. The DIV with the error message start visible and then work fine.

I need to do this:

1. when "nickname" is not valid then just display the DIV with my custom message and format.
2. when page is loaded then the DIV have to stay hidden.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to configure knockout-validation to not show the error-messages. There are two ways.

The first is via binding:

```
<div data-bind='validationOptions: { insertMessages: false }'>
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: nickname" class="short" maxlength="30" />
    <div class="formRow rowErrorMsg" data-bind="visible: nickname.isValid() == false">
</div>
```

The second one is via code:

- Use the `ko.validation.init({ insertMessages: false });` function
- Use the `ko.applyBindingsWithValidation(viewModel, rootNode, { insertMessages: false });` function **contextual

A description of all configuration options can be found at: https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Configuration

If you have many fields you have to validate you could use an messageTemplate template instead of manually creating all the errorMessage divs.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. After digging for 3 hours on applyBindingsWithValidation, I finally found your answer and you are the only person that mentioned that validationOptions can be set in line on the data-bind of the element. You saved me!!!!!!!